# Docker registry that allows public (anonymous) pull

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I've been considering to use my own private docker registry to distribute some of my projects publicly. However, the moment you [add an authentication strategy](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#restricting-access) to your registry, you lose public pull access to all its images.

Is there an easy way to tell the registry some images can be anonymously pulled (not pushed, of course) - in the same way https://hub.docker.com/ works?

I've been reading through https://docs.docker.com/registry docs but so far I found nothing on the matter. I guess it's a use case covered in EE [Docker Trusted Registry](https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/dtr/2.3/guides/) and not included in the community version:

> DTR uses Role Based Access Control (RBAC) to allow you to implement fine-grained access control policies for who has access to your Docker images.

Answer (score 1):

You can check 3rdparty Registry projects that allow fine grain access like Portus or Harbor, I use harbor and the projects set as public can be pulled anonymously

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the most-starred "docker registry" projects on github and that two names popped up among the list. How is your instance of Harbor performance-wise? I was looking for something lightweight since I don't need that many options, but I guess it's also worth checking.

Comment: What's the mechanism that allows harbor to do this? What I observe in my own attempts is that docker pull first pings https://registry.example.com/v2/. If I require auth on that endpoint, the pull fails (even if the ultimate image could be pulled without auth). If I do not require auth on /v2/, then the pull of a private image fails, because the client does not provide credentials (even if it has them for that registry) because the /v2/ ping did not require auth.